# Check the last visited page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout, redirect

I try to get the last visited page, for example I want to know if the last visited page was Checkout, if the Checkout page was last visited page then redirect customer after registration or login to the checkout page, else redirect to the my account.

this is my code:

```
   public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {    
       if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }

         else{ 
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that in your observer:

```
public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {    
       $lastUrl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
       if(preg_match("#onestepcheckout/index#", $lastUrl)){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }

         else{ 
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }

   }
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your answer, I think  you help me last time with this code, I have a small issues with this code, can you tell me where I can put this code?

Comment: check the edited answer

Comment: is very strange we can talk in private?

Comment: all i want to do is to check first if the user was in the checkout page before, if is true after login must be redirected to checkout, now with this code is redirect me only to my account, even if I visited checkout page

Comment: the code from above should do that. What's the link of your checkout page ?

Comment: domain.com/onestepcheckout/index/

Comment: can you try it now...i've updated the answer..should work

Comment: still redirect to my account

Comment: ...On my local instalation of magento it's working, i don't know what's the problem on your side.   Are you sure that your observer it's even called ?...

Comment: yes is called, can we talk on messenger? please take a look on my network profile and get my yahoo id